# デスクトップのディレクトリは「/Users/ユーザー名/」ではないのでしょうか

Tags: python, windows

現在、pythonでファイルを読み込もうとして`open()`を使おうとしたのですが
そんなファイルは存在しないと、pythonからエラーを返されました。

デスクトップ上にtest.txtとしてテキストファイルを保存して、

```
f=open("test.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
```

↑このように入力しましたが、ダメなようです。

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/GTO'
```

何か原因は考えられますでしょうか。
作業ディレクトリの設定などは必要となるのでしょうか。

すごく基本的なことで詰まってしまったので、
ご回答頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: どのような環境でどのように実行しましたか？

Comment: ファイルが存在しないというエラーが出るなら、ファイル名が間違っているか、パスが間違っているということです。オープンしたいファイルのパスと、実行方法(コマンドラインで実行したのなら、実行した時のカレントディレクトリとコマンド)を質問に追記してください。

Comment: まだプラグラミングに疎いため
カレントディレクトリが以下の内容で正しいのかわかりませんが
出力結果を記載します。
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/GTO'

Comment: カレントディレクトリに`test.txt`は存在しますか？ または、`test.txt`のあるディレクトリはどこですか？

Comment: デスクトップ上にtest.txtとしてテキストファイルを保存しているのですが
異なるのでしょうか

Comment: デスクトップは例えばwindowsなら`/Users/GTO/Desktop` です。`GTO`ディレクトリと同じディレクトリではありません。ファイルを`GTO`ディレクトリに移動させて実行してみて下さい。

Comment: `f=open("/Users/GTO/Desktop/test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`でいけると思います。

Answer (score 1):

デスクトップは例えば Windows なら`/Users/ユーザー名/Desktop` です。
`/Users/ユーザー名`のさらに下のディレクトリです。
ファイルを`/Users/ユーザー名`のディレクトリに移動させて実行してみて下さい。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。やはりディレクトが異なっていることが原因だったのですね。

Answer (score 1):

対象のユーザのデスクトップ上のファイルを右クリック→プロパティを表示しますと「場所」というところにデスクトップのディレクトリパスが書かれています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確認することができました。